# How to create a div with max-width including the responsive padding?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a `div` which grows/shrinks based on the width of the outer element, using `min-width` and `max-width`. I now want to add padding to that `div`. The padding should be relative to the width of the content of the div, but apparently the padding is calculated using the width of the outer element and not the `div` itself. That's visible when increasing the available width of the outer element past the `max-width` for the `div`. My expectation would be that the padding would stay constant, but instead it continues to grow.

I believe I could wrap the `div` in another `div` and set the width on the outer `div` and the padding on the inner `div`, but is there a cleaner way, without requiring a second `div`?

```css
#test {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 5%;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  This block should have relative width based on the size of the outer element,
  but padding relative to its own width. Its width including padding shouldn't
  exceed 600px.
</div>
```

You'll need to use the fullscreen view of the snippet and play around with varying window sizes to see the mentioned effect.

Comment: Do you mean `box-sizing: border-box`? https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: @SuperDJ: Oh yes, indeed. Nevertheless, it doesn't fix the mentioned issue. I added it to the CSS in the question, so it's visible that the problem is still there when running the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right, padding in percent is always based on the width of the container. See [official definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties).

Solution: media queries.

```css
#test {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;         /* 5% of 400 px, for narrow screens */
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
#test {
  padding: 5%;         /* 5% of container width, for medium screens */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
#test {
  padding: 30px;         /* 5% of 600px, for wide screens */
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  This block should have relative width based on the size of the outer element,
  but padding relative to its own width. Its width including padding shouldn't
  exceed 600px.
</div>
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I want a continuous scaling of the padding based on the width, not based on certain break points.